# CSRF verification failed request aborted in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a problem where when trying to log in or creating an account it shows a csrf token error. Everything works fine when I run my django project locally from my pc via `manage.py runserver`
I uploaded my project to pythonanywhere and I get "CSRF verification failed request aborted" error in django.

Here's my:

login.html file

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="w-50 mx-auto">
        <h1 class="mt-5 text-center">Login</h1>
        {% if description %}
            <p class="lead">Login to your account/p>
        {% endif %}
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
                <p></p>
                <a class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" href={% url "password-reset" %}>Password reset</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Middleware in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

forms.py file

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')


class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['password']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')


class PasswordForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StoredPasswords
        fields = ['account']
```

and views.py file

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', context={'title': 'Welcome to KPM'})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', context={'title': 'about'})

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Perhaps it is because I used crispy forms incorrectly?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you added your actual views to the question? I don't see any form being passed to the context in the view `login` yet you appear to be rendering one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my browser, I needed to enable all cookies, the login view was not needed.